# making a timer 12 am from now

Tags: java, android

Hello i am creating a timer in my app but i stuck in getting seconds left in day end from now (12.00 AM) my timer basically need to show time left for today 11-59 PM. I successfully created a timer function which takes inputs in seconds and then start countdown but i am unable to calculate remaining  time of today in seconds

**Below is my timer function**

```
time = 30;
// Here i need time left for today end for example current time is 11.55 then remaining time is 5 minutes in seconds (300)

public void startTimer() { 
    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            textTimer.setText("0:"+checkDigit(time));
            time--;
        }   
        public void onFinish() {
            textTimer.setText("try again");
        }

    }.start();
}

public String checkDigit(int number) {
    return number <= 9 ? "0" + number : String.valueOf(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remaining time of today in seconds:

```
Calendar tomorrow = Calendar.getInstance();// creating a calendar for tomorrow at 12am
tomorrow.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
tomorrow.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
tomorrow.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
tomorrow.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
tomorrow.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

remainingSeconds = ( tomorrow.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis() ) / 1000
```